# why are transfered buffers neutered in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Javascript allows buffers to be transfered from a source thread to a Worker thread. Otherwise, the ArrayBuffer is copied, then passed to the worker. Transfered buffers are not accessible ("neutered") in the source thread [1]:

```
// create data that can be transfered
var arr = new Uint8Array(5);

// outputs: 5
console.log(arr.buffer.byteLength);

var worker = new Worker("some_worker.js");

// transfer the buffer
worker.postMessage({arr: arr}, [arr.buff]);

// the buffer vanishes. is "Neutered"
// outputs: 0
console.log(arr.buffer.byteLength);
```

I unterstand how the mechanism works. I am however curious why it was introduced. Why isn't the data shared between worker threads, like in a traditional threading model, which allows multiple threads to access the same
memory region?

---

Other phrasings of the same question for clarification:

**Why are buffer neutered on transfer? / What is the reasoning behind this mechanism? / Why was it introduced? Why can't memory regions be shared between Workers?**

I am looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

---

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage

Comment: Thanks, Michal Charemza. I added your sentence to the question as this was the reason for the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Transferable objects were introduced in Web Workers in order to improve performance versus copying objects (especially when we're talking about objects of big size). It can be parallelised to a comparison between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in common programming languages (such as C/C++).

The further restriction, that transferable objects cannot be used in the source worker thread, was probably added, so that it is guaranteed that there will be no race conditions between the 2 different threads (in order to facilitate the work of developers that do not have to care about that). Furthermore, there would also then be a need for a lot more concurrency primitives to be implemented in Javascript (such as mutexes etc.). In essence, the use of "transfer" means you just intend to transfer the data to another thread, not use them from 2 threads simultaneously, so we could say that the implementation makes sense.

In general, Web Workers were not designed as a shared-memory model, but as as a message-exchange model.

For further reading on performance difference, check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast?hl=en). You can also check [this](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53485), where there is a discussion why shared memory model has not been adopted for Web Workers in WebKit.

Comment: +1 for "In general, Web Workers were not designed as a shared-memory model, but as as a message-exchange model."

Citation from the last link: "It's a primary design principle of web workers that the complexities of doing proper multithreaded design will not be exposed to JavaScript developers."

Answer (score 6):

This is a very basic multi-threading question. If the Array was accessible in both the main thread and the worker, then a mutex lock would have to be implemented so that race conditions won't appear when accessing the buffer. Also, I think Array buffers are usually used when you want performance, but having a lock for reading/writing data from that buffer would make the worker slower.

I guess this is one of the reasons why the resource is "moved" and not shared.

**TL;DR**: multi-threading

Answer (score 4):

The reason is performance. The sent data is not copied,  the ownership of the ArrayBuffer is transferred to the receiver.

For shared memory, you should use [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer)

Answer (score 3):

Accordingly to the [WHATWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG) ML, the choice was to be [thread safe](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2010Sep/0120.html), because

> You can't share data between workers.  There is no (and there cannot be) any shared state between multiple threads of JS execution.

([source](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2010Sep/0122.html))

Also,

> We want to
>   make the source ArrayBuffer, and any ArrayBufferViews, zero length
>   upon posting them to a worker or back to the main thread. By
>   ping-ponging the same ArrayBuffer back and forth you can avoid
>   allocating new backing store each iteration.

([source](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2010Sep/0136.html))

Unfortunately, I do not find the discussion about specs, [the page](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/registry/trunk/public/webgl/doc/spec/TypedArray-spec.html) where it should be hosted gives 404, I'll try to find a copy somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

For using these concept in javascript you must use these coding ,

```
PostMesage(aMessage, transferList)
```

In transferList you must specify transferable objects, which contained in aMessage:

```
var objData =
{
    str: "string",
    ab: new ArrayBuffer(100),
    i8: new Int8Array(200)
};
objWorker.postMessage(objData, [objData.ab, objData.i8.buffer]);

On other side:

self.onmessage = function(objEvent)
{
    var strText = objEvent.data.str;
    var objTypedArray = objEvent.data.ab;
    var objTypedArrayView = objEvent.data.i8;
}
```

To use "transferable objects" you actually transfer the ownership of the object to or from the web worker. It's like passing by reference where a copy isn't made. The difference between it and the normal pass-by-reference is that the side that transferred the data can no longer access it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear *transfers* applies to both dedicated and shared workers as both use MessagePorts

> [[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#communicating-with-a-dedicated-worker)Dedicated workers use MessagePort objects behind the scenes.
>
> [[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#shared-workers)Communicating with shared workers is done with explicit MessagePort objects

postMessage is specified to transfer or clone based on *the caller's choice*:

> [[3]](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#message-ports)port.postMessage(message [, transfer] )
>   Posts a message through the channel. **Objects listed in transfer are transferred**, not just cloned, meaning that they are no longer usable on the sending side.

This however only indicates if the poster keeps a copy, usually based on efficiency, and not if any memory is shared.

When it comes to "**memory**" it is clearly specified that it **must not be shared irrespective of the worker type or wether data is transfered or cloned**:

> [[4]](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dedicatedworkerglobalscope)When a user agent is to run a worker for a script with URL url, an environment settings object settings object, and a URL referrer it **must** run the following steps:
>
> **Create a separate parallel execution environment (i.e. a separate thread** or process or equivalent construct), and run the rest of these steps in that context.

So now the question: why? Why **must** the user agent create a parallel execution environment for any and all types of workers?

Security? No. Efficiency? (since when is js efficient?), neither.

The reason is to be able to abide in or rather respect the whole of the specification. If you follow the [link [4]](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dedicatedworkerglobalscope) you'll notice at minimum:

> When a user agent is to terminate a worker it must run the following steps in parallel with the worker's main loop (the "run a worker" processing model defined above):
>
> 1)Set the worker's WorkerGlobalScope object's closing flag to true.
>
> 2)If there are any tasks queued in the WorkerGlobalScope object's event loop's task queues, discard them without processing them.
>
> 3)Abort the script currently running in the worker.
>
> 4)If the worker's WorkerGlobalScope object is actually a DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope object (i.e. the worker is a dedicated worker), then empty the port message queue of the port that the worker's implicit port is entangled with.

And that's just one part of the specification.

So again why? It's to be able to manage the totality of the events that take place in the worker space. Implementers **must** parallelalize the workers or go completely insane.
:)

Answer (score 0):

**It seams to be motiviated by historical circumstances, as transferables were added to the spec after workers were introduced as message-passing API [1] with the intention to make minimal changes [2] [3].**

---

[1] https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720083 (Request for implementation in Firefox)

[2] https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2014-May/037239.html

> *Because when the concept of Transferable was formalized in the HTML5
>   spec, there was a goal to make the minimal possible changes.*
>   Transferable was basically a generalization of MessagePort, which was
>   the only type that previously could be "transferred" to a web worker.
>   Neutering is only a concept in spec text and not in the IDL. The
>   Transferable typedef doesn't have any associated methods. The only way
>   to neuter an object is to transfer it to a web worker. There were
>   requests to provide a "close()" method and make Transferable a
>   sub-interface of a new Closable interface. We resisted making those
>   changes because they would have essentially introduced manual memory
>   management to JavaScript.

[3] https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2014-May/037227.html

> First, some background. When typed arrays were designed, they were
>   specified with Web IDL and its ECMAScript binding. There were attempts
>   during typed arrays' development to throw exceptions on some
>   operations -- like out-of-range indexing -- but one by one these were
>   discovered to be incompatible with either Web IDL's or ECMAScript's
>   semantics like property lookup.

Comment: This is not a reason at all. Having shared resources would either require global interpreter lock, which would defeat the purpose of having Workers in the first place, or have synchronization objects, which would be rather alien in JS.

Comment: @transistor09 Can you elaborate why this is not a reason? Introducing a small patch to an existing facility instead of specifying and implementing a second, completely different system, makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: What you're quoting is *not a reason*; it is smallest *resulting change* of spec to allow having objects that are shared but owned by **only one** context at a time (for reasons already mentioned).